# Living quarters don't have power

Tags: fallout-shelter

The living quarters don't have power and I don't know why? I tried upgrading them, but it didn't work. I have a power generating room, but my living quarters still don't have power. How do I generate power in the living quarters?

Answer (score 1):

> Electricity doesn't travel forever. After some distance it gets weak, the same applies in the game. Any room that is too far away from the Power Generators/Plants will start losing power first. Easy fix if you put Power rooms in the center of your Vault or just make more near the rooms that keep losing power.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3acsna/why_does_my_power_keep_going_out_in_rooms/)